Implementing a system assigned key in Mongo
We are using libbson mongo-c-driver version 1.15.0, and trying to convert database files from DISAM to Mongo. The code uses system assigned keys (sak) for records in some tables - which are numbers in a sequence, generally starting from 0 or 1 (1, 2, 3, and so on). This acts as the primary key. But Mongo uses object ids. How do we generate object ids in a serial manner?
We use a function called get_next_available_sak (in C) which has to provide the next available key. But the problem is we have to also utilize the keys of records which have been deleted for this. So the algorithm is:

Find the sak of the deleted record.
If no missing sak is found from step 1, use the next available sak.

For example, in a table for students, lets say we have the roll number which is the sak. This increases from 1 to 100 for a 100 students. If one student is transferred to a different school, her record is deleted. If a student with roll number 25 is transferred to a different school, record with sak 25 is deleted, and it is available to be assigned to the next student who joins the school. When the next student joins, she will be assigned sak 25. The next student will get sak 101 provided there is no other missing sak.
How do we do this with Mongo?
We have tried some really complex aggregates for this, and feel that it is too complicated to understand and maintain, especially in C - something like:
[
{$sort:{_id: -1}},
{$limit:1},
{$project:{_id: 0,maxSerialNumberPlusTwo: {
$add: ["$_id", 2]
}}},
{$project:{_id: 0,
list: {
$range: [0, "$maxSerialNumberPlusTwo"]
}}},
{$lookup:{
from: "student",
localField: "list",
foreignField: "_id",
as: "matched_docs"
}},
{$addFields:{
matched_ids: "$matched_docs._id"
}},
{$project:{
missing_sak: {
$setDifference: ["$list","$matched_ids"]
}}},
{$unwind: "$missing_sak"}
]

Another alternative is to sort all the records descending, get the first one, and 1 to it. But this only gives the next sak (point 2), without first checking if there is any missing sak (Point 1).
Q. Why is all this important? Why can't we just use objectid instead of sak?
A: Because of legacy code. Since this is a conversion-only project, certain things won't work if we change strategy.
Are there alternatives to get the next sak using Mongo? Hopefully an easier query than the one we are using? Or other ways or ideas of dealing with this issue?
Currently, system is generating sak by the following way for DISAM:

sak = 1
Check if this sak is found in table.
If yes, increment sak by 1.
If not, return sak.

This works currently with DISAM because the DISAM db is in the server, and the calls don't cost much. But Mongo db resides in a different server than the application server, and if there are a few million records to do this for, it results in a performance issue.

There is no required for _id to be an ObjectId, if your software can generate new sak's, use those as the value for _id when inserting.

Do I get it right that there is never more than 1 client connected to the database? Remove concurrency from the equation would simplify things dramatically.

Nope, there can be multiple clients connected to the database.

How do you resolve race condition when 2 clients search for a gap in sak numbers?

One of the processes(/clients) will lose with a duplicate index error. This should call the function to get_next_available_sak and try again

Then I guess you can apply your pipeline to find the gap. There is very little  room to simplify it, but you can move it away from your application to the DB side and create a view https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/core/views/ that runs the pipeline and returns a single number. As a side note, I would left _id as ObjectID and created a separate unique key sak or id for your application logic.

I am trying to research the code if I can somehow just use the _id itself, and get rid of the sak. Will update here after I have found a way. I don't like implementing the pipeline in C. Hard to understand and maintain.


How do we generate object ids in a serial manner?

You do not. ObjectId is monotonically increasing thanks to the timestamp component. This gives best chances to generate unique value without central authority.

How do we do this with mongo?

Painfully. It's a decentralised database aiming speed and availability at scale. The price is eventual consistency, which plays against your usecase.
You could try atominc $inc combined with 2-phase commit technique or transactions rather than trying to do it in a single pipeline.

certain things won't work if we change strategy.
Are there alternatives to get the next sak using Mongo?

You may want to elaborate on the "certain things" I reckon. Otherwise value of the suggested alternatives from people without domain knowledge would be quite questionable.
